# How to get the time to load a webpage in C# without knowing the URL?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get the time that it takes to load a webpage in C#. But the code is just like this

```
_browser.Link(Find.ByText(m.Groups["MethodValue"].Value.Replace("<SP>", " "))).Click();
```

which just clicks the image or button to go to the webpage.
So how can I get the time without knowing the URL? Or is there any way to get the URL of the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

declare a stopwatch `Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();`

in the browser.Navigating event

```
stopwatch.Start();
```

in the browser.LoadingComplete event

```
stopwatch.Stop(); 
int loadingtime = s.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```